# What manipulation of concurrency mechanisms there are with working with transactions and explicit locks?

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, transactions, locking

I work with c# and postgres and I have example:

1. I have a lot of dynamic tables in some schema. For example: "test_schema"."A", "test_schema"."B", "test_schema"."C", "test_schema"."C_Source", etc. Some tables are source, but some are dependents.
2. The value of table "C" depends on values of the tables "A" and "B". Tables have values:

   ```
    "test"."A" //source table
    |Id|Value| IsActual| Attribute | 
    |1 | 10  | false   |     1     |
    |2 | 20  | true    |     2     |

    "test"."B" //source table
    |Id|Value| IsActual| Attribute |
    |1 | 10  | false   |     1     |
    |2 | 20  | true    |     2     |

    "test"."C" //dependent table
    |Id|Value| IsActual| Attribute |
    |1 | 20  | false   |     1     |
    |2 | 40  | true    |     2     |

    "test_schema"."C_Source" // storing links table
    |Id|        ValueId               |         SourceValueId        |SourceTable|
    |1 | 1 //(from "test_schema"."C") | 1 //(from "test_schema"."A") |     A     |
    |2 | 1 //(from "test_schema"."C") | 1 //(from "test_schema"."B") |     B     |
    |3 | 2 //(from "test_schema"."C") | 2 //(from "test_schema"."A") |     A     |
    |4 | 2 //(from "test_schema"."C") | 2 //(from "test_schema"."B") |     B     |
   ```
3. I manipulate these values from the tables via code. I'm creating the system which to calculate values by related data.
4. The values for the table "C" calculate automatically when the field "IsActual" from the source tables are changed. The values of the tables "A" and "B" load and change by user from UI. For example: user1 are changing the field "IsActual" = true of the table "A" where "Id" = 1 then system starts calculating the related value of the table "C" by the SAME ATTRIBUTE.
5. I have to ensure the correctness / integrity of the calculation of dependent tables ("C").
6. If some user1 are changing the field "IsActual" = true of the table "A", the system is explicity locking this row (`for update`), then the full table "C" (`LOCK TABLE ... IN EXCLUSIVE MODE`) and another dependent tables, then the system is starting calculating.
7. If some user2 are changing the field "IsActual" = true of the table "B", the system is explicity locking this row (`for update`), then the system is trying to explicity lock the full table "C" (`LOCK TABLE ... IN EXCLUSIVE MODE`), but It can't because the full table "C" is locked by user1 and its transaction. The system is waiting when user1 unlocks the table "C".
8. the transaction2 (user2) could fail by timeout and the calculation won't be performed.

How can I ensure 100% chance of calculating dependent tables / values?
What mechanisms are there?

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I've edited. Can you suggest any mechanisms?